# typescript union number | number[] onChange use type passed in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hello I am running into an issue with typescript and react where I want to have a component that accepts the props

`interface Props { value: number; onChange: (newValue: number) => void;}`

or

`interface Props {value: number[]; onChange: (newValue: number[]) => void;}`

based on what is passed as the value to my component, ie if i pass `2` as the value I want the value and onChange to be typed as the `number` type and not the `number[]` and the reverse if I pass `[1,2]` as the value.

right now my workaround is using this interface for props:

interface Props {value: number | number[];onChange: (newValue: number | number[]) => void;}`

but the above interface requires that when we receive a value from the on change, we need to check if it is an array or not each time just to satisfy typescript. I want to avoid doing this check over and over. (it is done in the internal onChange of the component anyways)

is this possible with typescript?
Thanks in advance

**update:** this is the updated code however it still gets an error with the onChange

Error message: `Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<number>>' is not assignable to type '(value: number | number[]) => void'.`
`

```
interface Props<Type = number | number[]>{
    onChange: (value: Type) => void;
    value: Type;
}
export const Comp = <Type extends number | number[]>({
    onChange,
    value,
}: Props<Type>) => {
    const onValueChanged = (_e: Event, val: Type) => onChange(val);
    return <Component value={value} onChange={onValueChanged} />
}
```

The error is coming from the onChange function here

```
...
const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0);

return (
    <Comp
       onChange={setValue}
       value={value}
    />)
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.

```
interface Props<T = number | number[]> {
    value: T
    onChange: (data: T) => void;
}

// If you pass number, onChange will provide number. number[] otherwise
function AB<T>(props: Props<T>) {
    // Your logic here
}
```

Comment: @devashish doesn't quite work, I updated the question